# R error condition has length > 1

Tags: r

Hi i am getting this error:

> Error in if (x < min) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (x < min) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I have seen this error in others post but his solutions don't fix it,
I think this may be a different case

My code:

```
min <- data[1,2]

for(i in data){

  if(data[i,2] < min){

    min <- data[i, 2]

  }

}
```

The column that I am using(the second) all are numeric values

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your for loop to `for(i in 1:nrow(data)){...` then it will work.

I would not call your variable min because that is the name of the function which you should be using instead such as:

tmp=min(data[,2])